# Count substitutes per line

Tags: regex, bash, perl, awk

I have a (BIG) file containing lines like:

```
foobar {} foo{} bar{} foobar{}{}
foo {} foodfg{} bar{} foogfdbar{}
line without brackets
foobdgar {} fdfgoo{} bga foodfbar{}{}
fdfgoobar {} fdfoo dbar{} fooddbar
```

now I want to replace every {} with {$MATCH_COUNT} **for each line seperately**
Meaning the output should look like this:

```
foobar {0} foo{1} bar{2} foobar{3}{4}
foo {0} foodfg{1} bar{2} foogfdbar{3}
line without brackets
foobdgar {0} fdfgoo{1} bga foodfbar{2}{3}
fdfgoobar {0} fdfoo dbar{1} fooddbar
```

How can I do this in perl or awk? I am not an expert in these languages so I would highly appreciate it if you could explain shortly what the code is doing.

My solutions so far that do not work like I intended:

Perl:

```
cat test.properties | perl -e 'while(<>){ $c=0; while(/{}/g){print "{$c}"; $c++} print "\n"}'
```

(replaces it like i want but doesn't keep the unmatched stuff)

Awk:

```
cat test.properties | awk '{ print "{" gsub(/{}/, "") "}" }'
```

(replaces every line with a complete count - not what I want)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing you need here, is the `e` flag to a pattern substitute. This says 'evaluate' and lets you use code expressions in regex replacements. Like `$count++` for example :)

E.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) {
   my $count = 0; 
   s/{}/"{".$count++."}"/ge;
   print
}

__DATA__
foobar {} foo{} bar{} foobar{}{}
foo {} foodfg{} bar{} foogfdbar{}
line without brackets
foobdgar {} fdfgoo{} bga foodfbar{}{}
fdfgoobar {} fdfoo dbar{} fooddbar
```

Seems to do what you want.

To simpify this down:

```
perl -pe '$c=0; s/{}/"{".$c++."}"/ge' text.properties
```

Note the `-p` flag to perl - it wraps your code in a loop, such that it works a lot like 'sed' would (e.g. `while ( <> ) {` and `print` each line as you go) which is what you're trying to do in your example 'by hand'.

You could, if you were so inclined also use the `-i` flag for in place editing.

I would also note - `cat | awk` or `perl` is redundant - both take file arguments when executing things.

Comment: It worked like a charm thank you!!
i didn't know about the `e` flag - now it all makes sense :D

Comment: Alt: `perl -pe'$c=0; s/{\K(?=})/$c++/ge' text.properties`

Answer (score 2):

FS = field seperator.

NF = Number of fields that has been built splitting the line.

'printf' is like the C-Standard function.

```
cat test.properties | awk 'BEGIN{ FS="{}" }{ for(i=1;i<NF;++i) { printf "%s{%i}", $i, i-1; } printf "\n"; }'
```

Comment: this prints {1} at the end of every line  
and doesnt start at {0}  - 
otherwise i like the FS approach

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
$ awk '{i=0; while(sub(/{}/,"{" i++ "}"));}1' file
foobar {0} foo{1} bar{2} foobar{3}{4}
foo {0} foodfg{1} bar{2} foogfdbar{3}
line without brackets
foobdgar {0} fdfgoo{1} bga foodfbar{2}{3}
fdfgoobar {0} fdfoo dbar{1} fooddbar
```

Explained:

```
{
    i=0                            # initialize i to 0
    while(sub(/{}/,"{" i++ "}"));  # while replacing with increasing i do nothing else
} 1                                # implicit print
```